# Session is getting reset in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, iis-7.5

I am running an ASP.NET 4.0 application with single sign on using IIS 7.5. I want my session not to be timeout till 365 days and set the value in web.config file. We are using "SQLServer" session mode. I have done the following

1) Set timeout to 365 days in web.config.
2) Set to use SQLServer session mode in web.config.
3) Set the application pool to use session timeout which is given in web.config file.

Even after modifying with these changes we are getting the problem as we are not able to access web server and when we click on any button to refresh, page is getting redirected to single sign on login page means session is getting reset.

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you want your session to run for so long?

Comment: It could possibly be the application pool recycling. http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/periodicrestart

Comment: Thanks sr28 for the reply "As per our requirement we need to run session for atleast 2 days."

Comment: Thanks Steve for the reply.The App Pool also has been configured not to recycle. Still facing this issue.

Comment: Phani - to alert someone to your reply use the '@' sign in front of their name. Also, have you tried confirming the session timeout by accessing the Session.TimeOut property to ensure it's being set to what you have in the web.config?